# Same message to several services

Tags: msmq

I have one MSMQ queue which is listened by five windows services. I used BeginPeek and PeekCompleted event for this purpose. My problem is among five services, only one service is the right recipient of the message. All four just read message, but no action is performed. This can only be identified when we read MQ message.
Now, I added a code in my services to check, if the criteria matches and the message is being processed by the right service, then I am using Receive to dequeue the message from MSMQ. Is that a good idea?

Secondly, If the message doesnot satisfy condition and all five services just peeked it, but not received, the message still lies in queue. I understand. But the same message is being processed infinite times, as the message was never removed.

```
private void queue_PeekCompleted(object sender, PeekCompletedEventArgs e)
{
MessageQueue queue = (MessageQueue)sender;
//Message msg = queue.EndPeek(e.AsyncResult);
Message msg = e.Message;
//Read message and check if the criteria matches
if(CriteriaMatches)
{
   queue.ReceiveById(e.Message.Id);
}


queue.EndPeek(e.AsyncResult);
queue.BeginPeek();
 }
```

Appreciate your help.
Thanks,
Fayaz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the messages to expire after a set (short) period. They will then move to the dead letter queue where you can have another service waiting for arrivals. This service could then raise an alert, for example, as soon as a message arrives.

Comment: But, this will block all messages in queue.

Comment: How? The message will no longer be in your main queue.